# movement in the tank game JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, game-physics, game-development

I am creating university project, it is a tank game, in this game we use 2D array as a map (we are able to change map by changing values of the array) and tank traverse by KeyEvent, i need to do an obstacle by block (which is one of the cell of the array), if tank intersect block it can not move. Is there way to do it in my code?

```
public class Tank extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
Timer tm = new Timer(1, this);
int tankX = 270, tankY = 270, velX = 0, velY = 0, direction = 1;
int bulletX = 330;
int bulletY = 330;


String[][] map = {
        {"B", "S", "B", "S", "B", "S", "B", "S", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "W", "0", "0", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "T", "0", "0", "0", "T", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "W", "0", "0", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "G", "0", "B"},
        {"B", "S", "B", "S", "B", "S", "B", "S", "B"},
};
public Tank() {
    tm.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
}


public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < map.length; j++){
            switch (map[i][j]){
                case "B":
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case "S":
                    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    break;
                case "W":
                    g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    break;
                case "T":
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    break;
                case "0":
                    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    break;
            }
            g.fillRect(i*64,j*64,64,64);
        }
    }
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(tankX, tankY, 64, 64);
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    if (direction == 1) {
        g.fillRect(tankX + 20, tankY, 24, 24); //UP
    }
    if (direction == 2) {
        g.fillRect(tankX + 20, tankY + 40, 24, 24); //DOWN
    }
    if (direction == 3) {
        g.fillRect(tankX + 40, tankY + 20, 24, 24); //RIGHT
    }
    if (direction == 4) {
        g.fillRect(tankX, tankY + 20, 24, 24); //LEFT
    }
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillOval(bulletX, bulletY, 14, 14);
```

}

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (tankX < 0){
        velX = 0;
        tankX = 0;
    }

    if (tankX > 530){
        velX = 0;
        tankX = 530;
    }

    if (tankY > 445){
        velY = 0;
        tankY = 445;
    }

    if (tankY < 0){
        velY = 0;
        tankY = 0;
    }


    bulletX = tankX + 24;
    bulletY = tankY + 27;
    tankX = tankX + velX;
    tankY = tankY + velY;
    repaint();
}



boolean Interception(){
    int y = bulletY/64;
    int x = bulletX/64;

    if (map[x][y] == "B"){
        map[x][y] = "0";
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void fire(){
    while (bulletX > 0 && bulletX < 530 && bulletY > 0 && bulletY < 530) {
        if (direction == 1) {
            bulletY--;
        }
        if (direction == 2) {
            bulletY++;
        }
        if (direction == 3) {
            bulletX++;
        }
        if (direction == 4) {
            bulletX--;
        }
        if (Interception()){
        }
        repaint();
    }
        destroyBlock();
}

void destroyBlock(){
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            fire();
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        velX = -1;
        velY = 0;
        direction = 4;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        velX = 1;
        velY = 0;
        direction = 3;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        velX = 0;
        velY = -1;
        direction = 1;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        velX = 0;
        velY = 1;
        direction = 2;
    }
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    velY = 0;
    velX = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tank t = new Tank();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
    jf.setSize(576,576);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(t);
}
```

}

Comment: looks like swing (not javafx) - changed the tags

Comment: You haven't explained what the letters in the map array signify.  Check that your tanks don't occupy the same coordinates as an obstacle.  It's also a great idea to create an application model from plain Java getter / setter classes.  Your classes are doing too many things and are not easy to understand.